# How to conditionally send an email in crontab

Tags: bash

I am using the following function to find large files (> 40MBytes) for various linux users in my team. It is possible that some of them may not have files larger then 40MBytes. The output of `$DUMPFILE` gets emailed to each user in crontab.  Is there an intelligent way to detect that the `$DUMPFILE` does not have the file listing and hence there is no point in sending an email to that user?

```
function find_files_and_dirs {

    # $1 = base directory from where to start the search

    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "List of large files for user $USER in $1" >> $DUMPFILE 
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE

    cd $1

    find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f \
      -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES >> $DUMPFILE

    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "Save states for user $USER in $1" >> $DUMPFILE 
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE

    cd $1/shared_savestates

    find $1/shared_savestates -maxdepth 3 -user $USER -type d \
      -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES >> $DUMPFILE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to have the function return value depend on the result of the `find` command:

```
function find_files_and_dirs {

# $1 = base directory from where to start the search

echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "List of large files for user $USER in $1" >> $DUMPFILE 
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE

status=`find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME \ 
   -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES`
echo $status >> $DUMPFILE

echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "Save states for user $USER in $1" >> $DUMPFILE 
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
echo "***************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE


find $1/shared_savestates -maxdepth 3 -user $USER -type d -printf "%s %p\n" \
 | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES >> $DUMPFILE

## If the find command did not find anything
if [ -z "$status" ];
then
  return 1
else
  return 0
fi
}

find_files_and_dirs && sendmail_command
```

So, in your script, you will call the function and then send the mail *only* (that's what the `&&` does) if it exits correctly, i.e. returns a value of 0. I also removed the `cd` commands since they were not doing anything useful. You do not need to `cd` into a directory to search through it.

In my opinion, it would be better to create the DUMPFILE only if large files are found but I don't know what exactly you are trying to do so I left that unchanged. You could have the whole thing be much cleaner with something like:

```
function find_files_and_dirs {
## Save the lines you want to print into the variable
## $Lfiles for future use
read -d '' Lfiles <<"EOF"
***************************************************
***************************************************
    List of large files for user $USER in $1 
***************************************************
***************************************************
EOF

## Also save the shared_savestates lines
read -d '' Sstates <<"EOF"
***************************************************
***************************************************
    Save states for user $USER in $1
***************************************************
***************************************************
EOF

## Check for large files. This saves the output of the find 
## command into the variable $status
big_files=`find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES`
## Find the "shared_savestates" files
sfiles=`find $1/shared_savestates -maxdepth 3 -user $USER -type d -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES`


## If the find command did not find anything, i.e. if
## the variable $status is empty
if [ -z "$status" ];
then
    echo "$Lfiles" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "No large files" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "$Sstates" >> $DUMPFILE
    echo "$sfiles" >> $DUMPFILE
    ## Have the function return a value of 1
    return 1
 ## If the find command found big files 
 else
     echo "$Lfiles" >> $DUMPFILE
     echo "$big_files" >> $DUMPFILE
     echo "$Sstates" >> $DUMPFILE
     echo "$sfiles" >> $DUMPFILE
     ## Have the function return a value of 0, exit correctly
     return 0
 fi
}
## In bash "&&" means run the command on the left ONLY IF 
## the command on the left was successful. So, this line
## will run the send mail command ONLY IF large files were found.
find_files_and_dirs $1 && sendmail_command;
```

This way you avoid creating unnecessary files.

If the `sendmail` command is done from `cron` and not from within your script (which seems kind of strange) then, you could create a temporary file with the result of the find command and then query the file from `cron`. Keep everything as I have suggested above and:

```
echo "NO" > /tmp/find_result
status=`find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME \ 
   -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null && echo "YES" > /tmp/find_result | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES `
```

Then, from cron:

```
@daily your_bash_script.sh; grep YES /tmp/find_result && sendmail
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Linux scripting and am not clear. So in the following solution, I need to run find command twice on the same task one to detect if there is something and once I detect, I actually use it to dump into a file.  function find_files_and_dirs {

    status=`find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME \ 
     -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES`

  if [ -z "$status" ];
  then
    return 1
  else
    echo "****" >> $DUMPFILE
    ALL THE OTHER ECHO AND FIND COMMANDS FROM THE ORIGINAL FUNCTION
    SEND THE MAIL (within the funct

Comment: @user199889 I included the entire function in my answer to make it clearer. You are not running the `find` command twice. You are running it once and saving its output. So, if the command finds nothing, the output ($status) is empty. If $status is empty,  the function will return `1` and the mail will not be sent.